# Resizing and content loss problem with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been doing challenges from Frontend Mentor. I set 375 x 1502 for mobile view and it works fine.
But when I resize the height to 800, I lost my page partially. It is not like it crops the content to fit the screen. It gives a scroll bar for the content it can't fit, but not all the content. What am I lurking?

Here is the live site. Try resizing the height.
https://zeiyar-lynn.github.io/FM-002/

Here is the source code. https://github.com/Zeiyar-Lynn/FM-002

Comment: Please put minimal example that reproduces your issue IN the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `height` to `min-height` in `.main` style.

```
main{
    min-height: 100vh; /* CHANGE height to min-height */
    font-family: 'lexend deca', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Comment: Let me ask one more thing. What if I want the same with width too? "min-width: 100vw" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set another media query:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
  #frame {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 330px);
    grid-template-rows: 440px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```